# jquery auto complete does not work on every field

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery

I use codeigniter. And I have three field with the class `.eghamat`. I don't know why autocomplete doesn't work  in the two first fields (`INSERT VALUE HERE 1`, `INSERT VALUE HERE 2`) but works in the third(`INSERT VALUE HERE 3`).

The problem might come from one of the following:

- The php code
- the `$.each` loop
- the ajax call

Does someone see what's wrong?

html:

```
<div class="bg_units bu0">
        <div class="auto_box">
                <b class="search_hotel">
                <div class="mediumCell">
                        <input type="text" name="hotel_auto" class="eghamat" placeholder="INSERT VALUE HERE 1">
                </div>
                <ul class="list_autobox_hotel">
                </ul>
                </b>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="bg_units bu1">
        <div class="auto_box">
                <b class="search_hotel">
                <div class="mediumCell">
                        <input type="text" name="hotel_auto" class="eghamat" placeholder="INSERT VALUE HERE 2">
                </div>
                <ul class="list_autobox_hotel">
                </ul>
                </b>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="bg_units bu2">
        <div class="auto_box">
                <b class="search_hotel">
                <div class="mediumCell">
                        <input type="text" name="hotel_auto" class="eghamat" placeholder="INSERT VALUE HERE 3">
                </div>
                <ul class="list_autobox_hotel">
                </ul>
                </b>
        </div>
</div>
```

php:

```
function auto_complete() {
    $hotel_search = $this ->input-> post('hotel_auto');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM hotel_submits WHERE name LIKE '%$hotel_search%' ORDER BY name asc");
    if($query->num_rows()==0){
        return '0';
    }else{
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
           $units = json_decode($row->units);
           $data[] = array('name' => $row->name, 'units' =>$units );
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.auto_complete_eghamat').live('keyup',function () {
    var $this = $(this),
    $div = $this.closest('div.bg_units'),
    bu_num =  '.' + $div.attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'auto_complete',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(dataObj);
            var id_name = $(bu_num+' .list_autobox_hotel').attr('id');
            $(bu_num+' .list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
            if (data == 0) {
                $(bu_num+' .search_hotel').show().html('<p><b>there is no</b></p>');
            } else {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('<p id="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</p>').appendTo(bu_num+' .list_autobox_hotel');
                });
                $('body').click(function () {
                    $(".list_autobox_hotel p").hide().remove();
                    $('.auto_complete').val('');
                    $('.list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
                    $('.list_autobox_hotel').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please rename `id="tour"` and  `id="hotel"`  cz html cannot have same ids multiple times

`id="tour"` 
and also

```
id="hotel"
```

appears 3 times in the code so please look into it.

Comment: you can instead add `class="tour"` and use `$(.tour)` selector

Comment: I remove all `id="tour"` and `id="hotel"`(i do not need to this ids),but the problem still exists. see demo my code [here](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

Comment: in above code aoutocomplete pops up when u incrementally add letters to each input field, 2nd alone doest work if 1st field is empty,same with 3rd if 1st and 2nd fields are empty, can you please elaborate more and what exactly your expecting

Comment: I want each input is the result separate, mean if typing value in input 1 result displaying in following same input 1, and as for other inputs...

Comment: `$.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('<p >' + value.name + '</p>').appendTo(bu_num+' .list_autobox_hotel');
                });` try this, i have just removed id part..

Comment: I changed, but the problem is not resolved, [see](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3364/discussion-between-run-and-selena-winter)

Answer (score 0):

could you please try it out. and let me know.your admin.js should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.list_autobox_hotel p').click(function() {               
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.eghamat').val($(this).text());             
            }); 

        $(document).click(function() {
            if($('.list_autobox_hotel').is(':visible')){
                $('.list_autobox_hotel').hide(); 
            }
            return true;

            });


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('#loadingDiv').hide() // hide it initially
        .ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

        ///////auto_complete///////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('.eghamat').live('keyup', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $div = $this.closest('div.bg_units'),
                bu_num = '.' + $div.attr('class').split(" ")[1];
            var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
            //alert(dataObj);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                //url: 'binboy.gigfa.com/admin/…',
                url: 'auto_complete',
                data: dataObj,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(bu_num);
                    var id_name = $(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel').attr('id');
                    $(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel').show().html('');
                    if (data == 0) {
                        $(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel').show().html('<p><b>there is no</b></p>');
                    } else {
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                            $('<p >' + value.name + '</p>').appendTo(bu_num + ' .list_autobox_hotel');
                        });

                    }
                },
                "error": function (x, y, z) {
                    // callback to run if an error occurs
                    alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: see, this don't worked: [link](http://binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

Comment: can u put some alert and check which function its triggering

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code

```
$('.eghamat').click(function(){
    var id  =$(this).attr('id');
    //Here you have the id select with it and put your code in it
});
```